# TypeScript syntax within a JS file - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've installed some third party library for React: [react-draft-wysiwyg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draft-wysiwyg)

While exploring the source code, i was surprised to see that my Visual Studio Code IDE gives me alot of syntax errors, within the JS files. For example, this function:

```
onEditorBlur: Function = (): void => {
this.setState({
  editorFocused: false
});
};
```

My editor tells me that "types can only be used in a TS file".

The package.json "main" filed points to an already bundled file, but when i try to switch it to the src folder, i get various errors, like "you need a special loader..."

Is there some way to use typescript within JS?

Comment: This is not valid TypeScript syntax afaik. Possibly Flow?

Comment: Ah yes, i see in the package.json various things related to Flow, including a special Babel plugin

Comment: Solutions to your problem may be available by telling vscode to treat .J's files as another type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to use typescript within JS?

No. But you can (and this project does) use flow: https://flow.org/

To use Flow with VSCode : https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode